# "Should be Closed because option..." in flagging menu does not offer real questions have real answers choice

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I flagged a question tonight (Wife interruption question with -2 dv). I noticed that in the "Should be closed because option" radio button when clicked does not give the reason of closure due to "Real question having real answers, aka a rant in disguise is explicitly off topic per SE community guidelines. I had to manually chose the "Needs a moderator's attention radio button option.

I suggest that closure due to question being a rant be added as a default choice.

Comment: at 3K, I see this choice. Close -> Off-topic -> third in the list there is "Real questions have answers..." Would you mind attaching a screen shot or just quoting items that are listed in flagging dialog under "Should be closed -> Off-topic"?

Comment: I definitely see it at almost 10K.  I use it a lot :)